# How to know if I used Iterative or Recursive DNS

Tags: recursion, dns, iteration, wireshark

How can I know using wireshark which ways I used Iterative or Recursive when I send a DNS?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It's right there in the flags. Just expand the protocol and look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @jonathon-reinhart mentioned in the comment, it's in the flag field,  Wireshark dissects and displays it as here:

[image: Wireshark dissection]